# Where are the in-the-box problem matchers defined?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I would like to see the source for these problem matcher, but can not find them in the vscode repo. What am I missing? Thanks!

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_processing-task-output-with-problem-matchers

Note: To me this doesn't seem like the appropriate place to be asking a question like this, but that's what the visualstudio.com/docs site said to do.

Comment: they are defined in the `package.json` of the extension

Comment: Can you add a link to the `$tsc-watch` matcher for example?

Comment: you can do a search of the source code for `tsc-watch` and if you want to modify it a bit see the Tasks doc page

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, the source for the problem matchers are found in the `package.json` of the built-in extensions. For example, the `$ts-watch` problem matcher is found here:

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/5a0ab56492d0c99f08028ca62ac3d59edb37f30f/extensions/typescript-language-features/package.json#L1055-L1089